# Changing visibility properties of a form from a class

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a multi-page program which changes its displayed elements by changing its visibility, which is written in the mainForm class(renamed from Form1) . Now as my program is getting more and more complicated I was thinking to make some kind of an external class in wich all these states would be changed becouse i have 26 text boxes and 3 options of displaying them which means I have  78 lines of textBox1.visibility = true; lines.

I have tried creating a class and changing the modifiers of all the textboxes to public and created an instance of form1 in my interfaceClass (MainForm mainform = new MainForm();) but this does totally not change anything to my form at all although no syntax or runtime errors happen.

I just want maybe some suggestions on how this can be realized if it can be at all.

Comment: Have some code to provide ? By the way, a simple public method written directly in your form should be enough ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a separate class for this; just write a single method in your form called `CheckVisibility()` and call that wherever you need to make sure your controls are shown or hidden properly.  Include all of the necessary conditions and show/hide changes in that method.

Answer (score 0):

Set the control to public in the designer:

```
public System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
```

Create a new class and for example rename it to exampleClass

```
public class exampleClass
{
    public static Form1 frm;

    public static void HideButton()
    {
        frm.button1.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Add this after Form1 InitializeComponent:

```
exampleClass.frm = this;
```

Now you can hide the button from anywhere you want:

```
exampleClass.HideButton();
```